# Application running out of memory after adding adMobs Banner

Tags: android, bitmap, admob, out-of-memory

I keep getting the following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 9961068 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 5MB until OOM
```

In my application I have 2 different ad units for 2 different activities. Each activity is linked to each other with a button. However, when I get to the 3rd activity the error shown above pops up and the app force closes. This didn't happen before I added the ads.

It seems like it runs out of memory when it tries to show a scaled bitmap but the bitmap is only 488x567px. I am using the following to show the image where myPlayer is an imageView:

```
myPlayer.setImageResource(playerTypes[3]);
```

What can I do to cut down on the memory the app needs?

Here is a snippet of the first Activity that is shown:

```
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Here is a snippet of the next activity shown:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "<ad-unit-id>");
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    begin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(players.getText().toString().equals("") || getTotalPlayers() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "How many players?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PlayerAssign.class);
                intent.putExtra("PLAYER_COUNT", "" + getTotalPlayers());

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Both of the above activities dont have any images besides a background image set in the xml file.

The next activity is where the error occurs.

```
show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(!myPlayer.getTag().equals(R.drawable.contenthidden)){
                Toast.makeText(PlayerAssign.this, "Press Next Player", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if(numClicked <= numPlayers){
                numClicked++;
                int rand = (int) (Math.random()*100);
                Log.d("rand",""+rand);
                if(rand<25 && numMafia != numMafiaAdded){
                    myPlayer.setImageResource(playerTypes[0]);
                    myPlayer.setTag(playerTypes[0]);
                    numMafiaAdded++;
                }else if (rand<50 && numDoctor != numDoctorAdded){
                    myPlayer.setImageResource(playerTypes[1]);
                    myPlayer.setTag(playerTypes[1]);
                    numDoctorAdded++;
                } else if (rand<75 && numDetective !=numDetectiveAdded){
                    myPlayer.setImageResource(playerTypes[2]);
                    myPlayer.setTag(playerTypes[2]);
                    numDetectiveAdded++;
                }else if (rand<100 && numVillager != numVillagerAdded){
                    myPlayer.setImageResource(playerTypes[3]);
                    myPlayer.setTag(playerTypes[3]);
                    numVillagerAdded++;
                }
            } else {
                myPlayer.setImageResource(R.drawable.setupcomplete);
                myPlayer.setTag(R.drawable.setupcomplete);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am using setImageResource() to set the image, should I use this instead?

Comment: i added snippets of code above @Yvette